# How to use distance function dtw in clasifier fitcknn

Tags: arrays, matlab, classification, knn, dtw

(Matlab R 2019b)

I used `@dtw` function as distance function in `fitcknn` classifier. 
The error massage says that the dimensions of two arrays of input to `dtw` are not the same.

I changed the function `dtw` to show the dimensions of the arrays and I found that the first print is correct (both x and y are one dimension) but the second print is not. After that the error message appears.

This is the code:

```
function [Mdl,Y,pred,gav,gavClass] = test_fitcknn()
    %Tests fitcknn
    % 2020-05-02
    load Y.mat Y;
    load pred.mat pred ;
    Mdl=fitcknn(pred,Y,'Distance',@dtw);
    gav=mean(pred);
    gavClass=predict(Mdl,gav);
end
```

And this is the error message:

```
Error in test_fitcknn (line 8)
    gavClass=predict(Mdl,gav);

Caused by:
    Error using dtw (line 91)
    The number of rows between X and Y must be equal when X and Y are matrices

 pred is the input data 60X156 real
 Y is 60X1 cell output  character string
```

I have saved data in this way:

```
save y.mat y
save pred.mat pred
```

Best regards
Alavi